Break a hline between two slide
sorry if this topic exists somewhere, I didn't find it.
I'm making some slides with beamer and I'm struggling to break a tabular between two slides.
This is the best I can get :
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\renewcommand<>\cellcolor[1]{\only#2{\beameroriginal\cellcolor{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \cline{2-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & header 1 & header 2 \\
    \hline
    topic 1 & \onslide<2->{A & B} \\ 
    \hline
    topic 2 &\onslide<2->{C & D} \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


But I would like something like this :

And I can't get there, because the
\cline{1-1} \onslide<2->{\cline{2-3}}

doesn't work..
Thanks for your help ! :)

You could use the tabularray package:
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}

% from https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/429#issuecomment-1672666912
\NewTableCommand{\beamerTemporal}[4]{\temporal<#1>{#2}{#3}{#4}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={ccc},
  hline{1} = {2-3}{solid},
  hline{2} = {1-3}{solid},
  vline{1} = {2-3}{solid},
  vline{2} = {1-3}{solid},
}
    & header 1 & 
    \beamerTemporal{2-}{\SetVline{1}{}}{\SetVline{1-3}{}}{} 
    header 2 & \beamerTemporal{2-}{\SetVline{1}{}}{\SetVline{1-3}{}}{} \\
    topic 1 & \visible<2->{A} & \visible<2->{B} \\ 
    \beamerTemporal{2-}{\cline{1}}{\cline{1-3}}{}
    topic 2 & \visible<2->{C} & \visible<2->{D} \\
    \beamerTemporal{2-}{\cline{1}}{\cline{1-3}}{}
\end{tblr}%
\end{center}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Oh waw, thanks ! I was stuck with tabular,I didn't thought to change the environnement. Thanks again :)

@Cla-Jan You're welcome!

You could use a NiceTabular with the options hvlines and corners as provided by the nicematrix package (this solution only works with \only, because we don't want things to be parsed if they are not printed):
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines, corners]{ccc}
     & header 1 & header 2 \\
    topic 1 & \only<2->{A} & \only<2->{B} \\
    topic 2 & \only<2->{C} & \only<2->{D} \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


It is generally better that \only (and other similar commands) don't span multiple cells. In this case, however, \only<2->{A & B} would also work.

Wow! That's really  much shorter! Nice!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Apart from the parsing issue, \onslide seems to work not as expected in the NiceTabular environment. You also used \visible instead in your original answer, right? At least, you can't put a cell delimiter inside, I think.

I used \visible only for the content inside the cells, to make sure that the cells have the same size on all overlays.

I see. Well, it seems that \onslide can't be used with the nicematrix package in the same way as the OP did in their original code. But it doesn't matter in this case anyways.

I did not try with nicematrix in particular, but as a general rule \onslide should better not span over multiple cells in tables, aligns and similar situations.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Probably \only should not span either, \only<2->{A} & \only<2->{B} would, of course, also work here. Maybe I should edit my answer.

I think in this particular situation the \only<>{A & B} should be harmless. Personally I prefer \only<2->{A} & \only<2->{B} to not temp users to use this in other situations.
